# MoviePy swelling effect trembling

Tags: python, moviepy

I tried to use moviepy to create a swelling effect. But the result looks trembling. You may test my code on your machine and watch the swelling effect. Remember to set the size to your test image when CompositeVideoClip.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

imgclip = ImageClip('test.png')
imgclip = imgclip.set_duration(3).set_start(0)

imgclip = imgclip.resize(lambda t : 1+0.05*t)

imgclip = imgclip.set_position(('center', 'center'))

CompositeVideoClip([imgclip],size=(512,512)).write_videofile('./Result.mp4',
                        codec='libx264',
                        fps=24)
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed `set_position(('center', 'center'))` and it fixed the problem for me.